# $interval stopping prematurely

Tags: angularjs, setinterval

I have an interval set in Angular, but it's not acting as expected. Here's the code:

```
        $scope.init = function() {$interval(function () {
        $scope.direction = 'left';
        $scope.currentSlideIndex = ($scope.currentSlideIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentSlideIndex : 0;
        }, 1000);
    };
```

`slides` is 3 items long.

This interval goes three times. Once `$scope.currentSlideIndex` equals 2, it just stops. It should, as you can see, become 0 the next time through and keep on going. But it doesn't. Any thoughts as to why it would just stop?

Interesting to note:

I increased the number of items in the array, and it still stops at 3 iterations.

I decreased the number of items in the array to 2 and it properly cycled back to the beginning for one item, then stopped - after the third iteration.

Something is stopping this at three iterations.

Thoughts?

---

### UPDATE

It's a time issue. It's not the number of iterations. It's the three seconds! If I increase the time to 2 seconds, it goes once through. If I decrease to half a second, it cycles around and makes it through.

Why would this die after three seconds?!?

Comment: try removing that `function` wrapper! think it's what effecting the `$digest loop` . [info][1]


  [1]: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: could u make a code example in plunker or something? I have a feeling that this might be more then just a time issue...

Comment: I'm having trouble making a plunker out of it, but here's the dev site itself. I'm trying to make that slideshow on the front page scroll itself. I have it set with 1 second now, for testing. I also have currentSlideIndex and slides.length render underneath the slide show so I can see what's happening. The JS is in HomeController.  http://www.gelerinter.com/dev_sites/lksu/#/

Comment: It might be related to the news ticker. I notice that the timeout/interval set on the newsticker is three seconds

Comment: Found it! The beginning of the news ticker interval clears out the intervals.Now I just need to figure out how to fix it.